# OllyDbg: How to set a conditional breakpoint for a value anywhere in the stack?

Tags: ollydbg, debugging, breakpoint

I know how to set conditional breakpoints on a register, but how can I have a breakpoint trigger if a specific value (say, 0x12345678) appears **anywhere** in the active call stack frame?

Comment: In x64dbg you could do this by setting a watch on every stack address, probably you could write a plugin that scans a stack page on every step but it's going to involve checking a lots of addresses, slowing everything down massively.

Comment: @mrexodia Thanks, I will give x64dbg a try. Actually, I'm only interested in the active call stack frame. I have edited my question accordingly. I suppose that makes it somewhat easier?

Comment: It would definitely be possible to write a plugin that scans the stack on every pause event with x64dbg. Plugin templates are available if you're interested.

Answer (score 5):

Not for Ollydbg, but I wrote a plugin called [StackContains](https://github.com/mrexodia/StackContains) for [x64dbg](http://x64dbg.com) that allows you to check if a value is present in the check during conditional tracing. This allows you to break as soon as the value becomes visible on the stack.

You use it like this:

[image: stack.contains]

This will break as soon as the value `00E60000` appears on the stack:

[image: break]

It should be easy enough to extend this plugin and tailor it to your needs...

Comment: That looks awesome, thanks for taking the time to write this plugin! If I can't get what I want in OllyDbg, I'll definitely try it. But the only problem is that I am not a C++ developer. I assume Visual Studio is needed to build the plugin? Or is there a compiled binary available?

Comment: I made binaries available https://github.com/mrexodia/StackContains/releases

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much.